# Apply "new" to only one dimension of multi-dimensional array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this C# program, and it has the following code:

```
/*10 data for one peprson */
private int[] data = new int[10];
private void SomeMethod()
{   
    /*More code*/
    this.data = new int[10];
    /*More code*/
}
```

This program calls this method when an event occurs, and every time that happens, this one-dimensional array gets a "new" instance of an array of size 10, and refresh the array. Kinda like resetting it.

Now, I was told to write a new program that does the same thing, except that there are 5 people now. So I created a 2-dimensional array like

```
private int[,] data = new int[5, 10];
```

which will be able to store 10 data for each of the 5 people.
Now I am at a loss on how to refresh/reset only one person's data from this 2-d array. I tried

```
private void SomeMethod(int index) /*index 0 - 4 for each of the 5 people*/
{
     this.data[index] = new int[10];
}
```

but this clearly does not work, and I get an error saying I am missing a dimension. Is there a way to achieve this?
For the time being, I am using

```
private void SomeMethod(int index) /*index 0 - 4 for each of the 5 people*/
{
     for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
         this.data[index, i] = 0;
}
```

When I tested it with the original code, I noticed that every time it got a "new" instance, it was assigning 0's to the array. Now the difference is that the original one is referencing the new instance with no data (and hence 0?), and the rewritten one is overwriting with 0's.

Do these two basically work the same way, program's-function-wise?

Comment: You might want to use a jagged/nested array instead of a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: A multi-dimensional array is sorta like a grid.  You are expected to index at an X and Y value.  There is not such thing as "rows" really (at least in the way you expect by assigning a new array at a single index).  Although there is nothing wrong with your last solution, as @SLaks said you might want to use a jagged array (an array of arrays).  That way you can replace an entire "row" at once.

Comment: Thank you all. Yeah, it seems like a jagged array should have been used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code you have. It's even likely faster than creating the new array. But if you really want to, you can use a jagged array instead:

```
private int[][] data = new int[5][];

//...

private void SomeMethod(int index) /*index 0 - 4 for each of the 5 people*/
{
     this.data[index] = new int[10];
}
```

But arrays seem weird for this. A `List<T>` might be better:

```
private List<int[]> data = new List<int[]>();
```

where you can then use the `.Add()` method as you get new records, and use the `Count` property to know how many you've added.

Moreover, it's common to find out the `int[10]` array was actually a stand-in for named fields, where each position in the array has meaning. In that situation, you're usually **much** better off building a `class` for this data, where each item in the array is a named field in the class (we'll just call it `MyClass` for now). Then you end up with something like this:

```
private List<MyClass> data = new List<MyClass>();
```

Comment: First time I realize that the initialization syntax is actually weird: `new int[][5]` seems more consistent to me, but it only works your way...

Comment: Upvote for the `List<T>` idea (though the property is called `Count`, not `Length`)

Comment: @RenéVogt Fixed, thanks. It's a silly thing, but if I don't have intellisense I have to look that one up. every. single. time. :(

Comment: Yeah me too lol I always mix up `Count` and `Length`. I also like the idea of using `List<T>`! Thank you all for help, I feel like I have gotten a bit smarter again.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Just remember that `Length` cannot change, but `Count` can (at least I think that's the reason for using different names).

Comment: That's why Resharper allows you to either type Count or Length for every such type and then substitutes correct one for you.

Comment: If he is not strictly tied to the array structure, via this being an assignment, or some very strange business requirement, why not skip the list of arrays altogether and really get at the heart of OOP.  Make a class object which has an a property int [].  This allows you to have a mutable number of objects, and allows you to add more properties as they become relevant to the project.